# If statement not working in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a mousedown function, but for some reason my if statement doesn't work in ie7 within the below code. Works in ie8 up, Chrome and FF.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$("dd.office").mousedown(function() {
    var btnTxt=$(this).text();
    for (var i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) {
      var teOffice = offices[i];
         if (btnTxt==teOffice[0]){  
           alert("Why Doesnt this work in ie7?");
         }
    }                   
}); 

var offices = [
['Office1', -33.3, 151.426039, 2],
['Office2', -33.9, 151.18743, 3],
['Office3', -37.9, 145.156302, 1]
];
```

page code

```
<dl>
<dt>Info</dt>
<dd class="office" >Office1</dd>
<dd class="office" >Office2</dd>
<dd class="office" >Office3</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Try putting a line before the if that is alert(btnText==teOffice[0]); and see what difference the different browsers give you.

Comment: are you sure your selector $("dd.office") is correct?

Comment: What do you get if you say: alert(btnTxt); alert(teOffice[0]); Without seeing more of your code/HTML I'd check that the element that the event belongs to is one that it makes sense to use `.text()` on. If it's a button as `btnTxt` implies you might want to say `var btnTxt=$(this).val();` (Does your existing code work in browsers other than IE7?)

Comment: Sorry I neglected to add that this problem is isolated to ie7. It works in all other browsers and ie versions 8+

Comment: Those alerts btw return the same value as expected

Comment: ie. 'Office1' when clicking <dd class="office"> text

Comment: Yes, thanks Jeremy. Confirmed as works in other browsers - sorry for the vagueness - first time posting newbie on this site.

Comment: @Mangrommet Just to rule out any whitespace issues, try this just above your "if" statement; `alert('[' + btnText + '], [' + teOffice[0] + ']');`.

Comment: does ie7 have some sort of console?? what does it say??

Comment: @Phil tried that and looks OK in ie7. that is, clicking on 'Office2' returns [Office2],[Office1] - [Office2],[Office2], [Office2],[Office3]

Comment: @DrStrangeLove I checked ie's dev tools console and do not get any output on mousedown

Comment: @Mangrommet No spaces between the square brackets and the text?

Comment: This was an error I wasn't aware of +1 -- may need to bring it to jQuery's attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `btnTxt` has a trailing space ().

Do one of the following:

1. `btnTxt = $(this).text().replace(/\s$/,'')`
2. `if (btnTxt.replace(/\s$/,'')==teOffice[0]){`

Comment: Not seeing the trailing space. Where is it exactly?

Comment: That worked, thank you vol7ron! I don't understand where that trailing space came from tho...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  It has something to do with the `jQuery.text()` function call.  jQuery uses `document.createTextNode` and when that happens the object has an empty childNode, perhaps the childnode is included as a space when jQuery constructs the string in IE7?  Not sure.

Comment: the `nodeValue` by itself has no trailing space.  It exists in the other jQuery somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the information vol7ron, much appreciated!
 
So a rule of thumb for future such scripts would be to always use replace(/\s$/,'') to avoid any random problems? 

Out of interest how did you detect this trailing space?

Thanks for your time, trying to master this darn language.

Comment: simple debugging, ***alerting/logging*** what wss in `btnText` showed an extra space at the end in IE9:Compatibility View.  You may want to add it, but there still might be a better reason then what I have found (it could be the type of element or something specific to that effect).  In this case, you should probably do it if you depend on IE7 - you could also do a `substring` on the `text()` value, or some other way of getting that last space off.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing comma inside the `offices` array.  IE chokes on trailing commas.

```
var offices = [
['Office1', -33.3, 151.426039, 2],
['Office2', -33.9, 151.18743, 3],
['Office3', -37.9, 145.156302, 1],
// ------------------------------^
// remove that.
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("dd.office").mousedown(function() {
    var btnTxt=$(this).text();
    for (var i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) {
      var teOffice = offices[i];
         if (btnTxt==teOffice[i]){  
           alert("Why Doesnt this work in ie7?");
         }
    }                   
});
```

Comment: Good catch, although doesn't necessarily explain why it works in other browsers ...

Comment: The OP's updated their question. `teOffice[0]` is correct given the new data

Comment: Wow thanks for the super rapid response! but I'm trying to match the array element teOffice[0] with my 'dd' text. Updated code above.